# Dynamics WHERE to native query in JPARepository

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have native query sql. How I can add dynamics "WHERE" to this sql. Sometimes user want filtr this result by idBran. Can I add to extra sql code if metod has parametr != null?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT product.id_product as idProduct," +
            " product.product_name as productName," +
            " brand.id_brand as idBrand," +
            " brand.name_brand as nameBrand," +
            " type.name_type as nameType," +
            " type.short_type as shortType," +
            " product_image.url_image as img," +
            " product_image.alt_image as alt," +
            " NVL(AVG(product_review.score),0) as score," +
            " COUNT(product_review.textreview) as countComments" +
            " FROM product" +
            " LEFT JOIN product_review ON product.id_product=product_review.id_product" +
            " JOIN brand ON product.id_brand=brand.id_brand" +
            " JOIN type ON product.id_type=type.id_type" +
            " JOIN product_image ON product.id_product=product_image.id_product" +
            " GROUP BY product.id_product",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM product",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<ProductsToListing> getAllProductsToListing(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Is idBran the only parameter you want to pass in this "dynamic" where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your Query the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 1=1 and (:idBrand is null or brand.id_brand = :idBrand)
```

where `idBrand` is the parameter in your repository method which can be `null` and this way the WHERE clause will be deactivated. If non-null value is passed in idBrand then the WHERE clause will be activated.

```
Page<ProductsToListing> getAllProductsToListing(@Param("idBrand") Integer idBrand, Pageable pageable); //supposing idBrand is an integer
```